# How to filter on a Sum() containing F()s?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have those two models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then I'd like to query all categories to find out how each is performing with its items:

```
(Category.objects.all()
    .annotate(
        sales_yesterday=Sum('items__quantity', filter=Q(items__created_at__date=yesterday)), 
        revenue_yesterday=Sum(F('items__price') * F('items__quantity'), output_field=DecimalField()), 
        sales_today=Sum('items__quantity', filter=Q(items__created_at__date=today)), 
        revenue_today=Sum(F('items__price') * F('items__quantity'), output_field=DecimalField())
    )
)
```

But `revenue_yesterday`and `revenue_today` don't filter for yesterday and today respectively, unlike `sales_yesterday` and `sales_today` which do. Meaning the `revenue_*` annotations do their aggregations over the entire table and that's not what I want. The challenge I'm facing is how to apply those needed filters on my `revenue_*` annotations and one of the approaches I've tried is something similar to what I've done with my `sales_*` annotations:

```
(
    revenue_today=Sum(F('items__price') * F('items__quantity'), 
        filter=Q(items__created_at__date=today), output_field=DecimalField())
)
```

Which only throws up an error:

`FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.`

And I'm not sure what I should do since I already set `output_field`, and it's not clear to me if I'm putting that filter in the right place or in the right way inside `Sum()`.

How do I solve this?